# Taking and skipping groups of strings?

Tags: java, python, c++, string

I worked with strings in a couple of languages and then something bothered me about how we can select characters or slices (substrings) from the strings. Like we can get substrings from a string or a character from a particular position, but I was not able to find any method or operator which returns certain slices of a particular length skipping particular characters. Below is the explanation.

So suppose I have the following string: `I am an example string.` From this string, I want to be able to get groups of string of let's say length `2` and skip certain characters, let's say `3`. Now to make things more interesting let's say I can start at any index, which for this example we'll take `5`. So the string which I should get from the above conditions should be the following: `anam sng`. Illustration below (`*` for take, `!` for skip).

```
                                    **   **   **   **
                               I am an example string.
                                    | !!!  !!!  !!!  !
                   Start Position --+
```

I know you could implement that using counting variables which keep track of each character whether to take or not using `if` condition. But I was thinking of a mathematical way or maybe even an inbuilt method or operator in some languages that could do the job.

I also searched whether Regex could do the job. But couldn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 1):

Generic solution: skip first `start` characters, when replace all occurrences of regex `(.{0,n}).{0,m}` by the first group.

Python:

```
import re

input = 'I am an example string.'
n = 2
m = 3
start = 5

print(re.sub('(.{0,%d}).{0,%d}' % (n, m), "\\1", input[start:]))
```

Java:

```
final String input = "I am an example string.";
final int n = 2;
final int m = 3;
final int start = 5;

final String regex = String.format("(.{0,%d}).{0,%d}", n, m);
System.out.println(input.substring(start).replaceAll(regex, "$1"));
```

C++11:

```
string input = "I am an example string.";
int n = 2;
int m = 3;
int start = 5;

stringstream s;
s << "(.{0," << n << "}).{0," << m << "}";
regex r(s.str());
cout << regex_replace(input.substr(start), r, "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex can do. You only need to try a little harder :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "I am an example stringpppqq";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.{1,2})(?:.{3}|.{0,2}$)");
    int index = 5;
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (index < s.length() && m.find(index)) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        sb.append(m.group(1));
        index = index + 5;
        System.out.println(index);
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

O/P :

```
anam sngqq
```

Answer (score 0):

Python don't have this kind of slicing, you must use a loop. But you can do it with a comprehension list:

```
text = 'I am a sample string'

s = 5  # start position
l = 2  # slice length
d = 3  # distance between slices

chunks = [text[p:p + l] for p in range(s, len(text),  l + d]
result = ''.join(chunks)
```

With a RegEx you can match a two-length string in a group and a three-length string.

```
import re

regex = r'(..)...'

found = re.findall(regex, text[s:])  # list of tuples
result = ''.join(f[0] for f in found)
```